# Docker step results to log file - Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

The Dockerfile contains several steps to build and create a docker image.

E.g. RUN dotnet restore, RUN dotnet build and RUN dotnet publish.

Is it possible to export the results/logging of **each step** to a separate file which can be displayed/ formatted in several Jenkins stages?

Comment: did you tried the supposed the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can export Jenkins build to log file as well using this plugin [**https://github.com/cboylan/jenkins-log-console-log**](https://github.com/cboylan/jenkins-log-console-log).

But if you want to view each step log in your Jenkins console log try this way.

Create a job and build your docker image from the bash script and run that script from Jenkins.

```
 docker build --compress   --no-cache --build-arg DOCKER_ENV=staging --build-arg DOCKER_REPO="${docker_name}" -t "${docker_name}:${docker_tag}" .
```

If you run this command from Jenkins or create bash file you will see each step logs as mentioned below. If you looking for something more let me know.

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testlog
[testlog] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins8370164159405243093.sh
+ cd /opt/containers/
+ ./scripts/abode_docker.sh build alpine base
verifying docker name: alpine
Docker name verified
verify_config retval= 0
comparing props
LIST: alpine:3.7
```

Now each step will be displayed under

[http://jenkins.domain.com/job/testlog/1/console](http://jenkins.goabode.com/job/testlog/1/console)

```
    Step 1/5 : FROM alpine:3.7
Step 2/5 : COPY  id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
 ---> 6645bd2838c9
Step 3/5 : COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
 ---> 635e37d9503e
.....
   Step 5/5 : ONBUILD RUN ls /usr/share/zoneinfo && cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Brussels /etc/localtime && echo "US/Eastern" >  /etc/timezone && date
 ---> Running in 7b8517d90264
Removing intermediate container 7b8517d90264
 ---> 3ead0f40b7b4

Successfully built 3ead0f40b7b4
Successfully tagged alpine:3.7
```